# Want to transpose the columns in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement to perform some sanity checks on a table using Scala.

My sample table is:

[image]

One could generate it with the following code:

```scala
val df = Seq(
    (1, "", "13-05-2020", Some("CSE")),
    (2, "PQR", "14022019", None),
    (3, "XYZ", "25-01-2018", Some(""))
).toDF("ID", "NAME", "Joining Date", "Branch")
```

Now, I want to perform Null Check and Date Check on all the columns. And I want the output be like:

[image]

I was able to generate a dataframe like this:

[image]

Please help me in populating the data into this DF.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have written so far (how you generate the data, how you created that final df and what you have tried to populate it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to compute some generic tests on all the columns of a dataframe.

Also you seem to consider that an empty string `""` is like a null value. Therefore I would start by replacing empty strings by null values (only for columns of type string).

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
val df_with_nulls = df.select(df.schema.fields.map(c =>
         if(c.dataType == StringType)
             when(col(c.name) === "", null).otherwise(col(c.name)) as c.name
         else
             col(c.name)
) : _*)
```

Then, just for the sake of a clearer code, I would define one function per check you want to perform. If they are not exactly what you want, feel free to tweak them:

```scala
val name = (c : String) => lit(c) as s"col_list"
val null_check =
    (c : String) => sum(col(c).isNull.cast("int")) > 0 as s"Null_check"
val date_pattern = "[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}"
val date_check =
    (c : String) => sum(col(c) rlike date_pattern cast "int") > 0 as s"Date_Check"
val distinct_values = (c : String) => collect_set(col(c)) as "Distinct_Values"
```

Finally, you can apply all of them in a generic way to all your columns like this:

```scala
df_with_nulls
    .select(array(df.columns.map(c =>
            struct(name(c), date_check(c), null_check(c), distinct_values(c))
    ) : _*) as "a")
    .select(explode('a) as "s")
    .select("s.*")
    .show(false)
```

while yields what you expect:

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------------------------------+
|col_list    |Date_Check|Null_check|Distinct_Values                   |
+------------+----------+----------+----------------------------------+
|ID          |false     |false     |[1, 2, 3]                         |
|NAME        |false     |true      |[PQR, XYZ]                        |
|Joining Date|true      |false     |[14022019, 13-05-2020, 25-01-2018]|
|Branch      |false     |true      |[CSE]                             |
+------------+----------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

My only warning would be not to use that on a column with too many distinct values. Indeed, since they are all aggregated to a single line, that would be very slow or worse, cause an OOM exception.